# Why are people using Quotes instead of Code?

Tags: discussion, formatting

We use the dollar sign link for code and the **"** for quotes right, Why am I seeing code formated as quotes? One example is this answer https://askubuntu.com/posts/146792/revisions

I have heard that some don't like how it looks, But it looks that way on purpose, It's mono-space so we can tell where the spaces are, and the font so we can tell the difference between certain letters and numbers

**Examples:**

> Code/Formated/as/quote oO0 1 IL il /\| some example of characters with code formated /sda/bin/abcde/bcda/bin.bin quote and it wraps around even when you don't have a break in text makes it confusing.

```
Code/Formated/as/code oO0 1 IL il /\| some example of characters with code formated as code and scrolls
And maintains the lines and you can see spaces clearly.
```

What is the proper way to format code?

Comment: Sorry, that annoyed me too much, had to change it :)

Comment: Sure thing, code is now formated as code.

Comment: Here is another example, this one is not from a new user, http://askubuntu.com/posts/146633/revisions

Comment: @mateo_salta sorry il keep that in mind.

Comment: Could there possibly be an automated script to find quotes and inline code based on key words and put it in a list to be reviewed by users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's incorrect. Fix it when you see it. Also new users tend to put a dollar sign too

> $ do this command

but our style here is no $, so usually I do them both at once.

Comment: awesome, I meant the little links for formating in my question, the "img" for images the " for quotes, ect. , but I have also seen the $ happen too, so good point.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen novices type/paste the `$` sign into the Terminal, a number of times. I have prewritten text I use as the edit summary when I edit a post to remove them: `removed leading $ because it is confusing to someone new to the command-line ("Do I type that?") and superfluous to the experienced` However, in some instances the `$` is the only thing telling the reader that the text is supposed to be entered on the command-line. In these situations, further editing is required when removing it (but this editing is necessary anyway because `$` doesn't mean anything to many users).

Comment: I only use $ on the first line of a multi-line paste showing the output from some command. If that's not ok, alternatives?

Comment: @izx I think that when you're pasting code that actually contains `$` as part of a prompt, that's fine. But I don't recommend providing instructions just by pasting blocks of text from a Terminal in which they have been followed. That's sometimes good as an example, but for instructions, just the commands that people run should be provided (and those without a leading `$`). It's often not sufficiently explanatory to just list the commands people should run, one after another, but when it isn't, the solution is to include prose (often in between) explaining things.